# CoreData Import Memory Overload

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I've asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538337/importing-with-magicalrecord-afnetworking) before, but I think enough has changed to warrent a new question.

I'm importing a large amount of data using MagicalRecord's `MR_importFromArray` method. It is being run in the background on an `NSOperationQueue` with a `maxConcurrentOperationCount` set to `1`. I'm importing in batches of 500 from files.

I have a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ryanjm/03235dfe6e4c41900482#file-gistfile1-m-L68) with all my code, but basically I'm looping over a [file](https://gist.github.com/ryanjm/03235dfe6e4c41900482#file-gistfile1-m-L104) which contains up to 500 objects. I then [import them and save them](https://gist.github.com/ryanjm/03235dfe6e4c41900482#file-gistfile1-m-L135-L136) using `MR_importFromArray`.

```
    NSArray *array = [NSClassFromString(name) MR_importFromArray:cleanedResources inContext:moc];
    [moc MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
    [moc reset];
```

I have everything saving and relating correctly. But my memory can quickly ramp up to 100+ MB and will often just crash the app completely. How can I assure that the import process isn't using much memory and releases it when it is done.

After each import I am calling `reset` on my `NSManagedObjectContext` but that doesn't seem to affect it at all. When I use Instruments to look at the memory/allocation usage of my app it says that the `MR_importFromArray` is where all the memory load is coming from. The Leaks tool doesn't find anything either.

From the allocations tool:

[image: allocations tool]

From XCode (just after getting memory warnings):

[image: memory inside XCode]

I'm not sure why Allocations only says 10MB are Live and XCode says 100MB (I'm still learning how to properly use Allocations).

I thought by resetting the context this would release all the memory related to that context.

I have a lot of jobs going into that operation queue, but like I said, only one is being run at a time so I would think that as they finish they would be removed from memory completely. But I'm not really seeing that type of graph in the Allocation tool.

What is causing the memory to pile up and not be released and how do I fix it?

## Update

In case it would be helpful here is the Call Tree from the Allocation's Tool (arrow pointing to the `MR_importFromArray` call:

[image: call tree]

And to answer Tom's question, the files that I'm opening are just JSON converted to NSDictionary and then saved to a file. When I save the JSON files locally they are around 200 KB. Again no binary attributes just strings, numbers, dates.

Comment: Is this 100MB+ memory all coming during one call to `MR_importFromArray`, or does it build up over multiple calls? Also, what does the data look like? Specifically, does it include binary attributes?

Comment: It builds up over time. The data is just basic JSON, no binary data.

Comment: A strategically placed `@autoreleasepool` block will likely allow you to reclaim memory before the outer pool is called for you. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html

Comment: @TomHarrington The closer I'm looking at the allocations it looks like it might be building up in one operation. I don't know of a way to mark the generation when a new operation starts, but I think that is what is happening.

Comment: @ChrisWagner - thanks, I didn't know about `@autoreleasepool`, I saw that `NSAutoreleasePool` was deprecated. What would you recommend putting it around?

Comment: @RyanJM is the `MR_importFromArray` spiking on the first pass and causing the crash or are you seeing it after calling `importEntities` a few times?

Comment: @ChrisWagner I'm importing 17 different models and each model might have anywhere from 1-5 files that it is importing from. Before it would get through most of the smaller models and then choke on the bigger ones. So I think is calling it a few times within the same class instance.

Comment: @ChrisWagner no it isn't being called in a loop. It is just called the once (see gist) per instance.

Comment: @RyanJM I would first try wrapping the `MR_importFromArray` call in an `autoreleasepool` block, but that is admittedly a naive approach. I'd have to run the app in Instruments myself to really narrow down where it would be most effective.

Comment: @ChrisWagner - I tried that and it doesn't seem to change anything. Thanks for the suggestion though.